# R - Get a list of tables matching regex pattern in a user function

Tags: r, regex, function

I wish to create a user function in R which merges multiple tables that uses regular expression to find these tables. In my situation, I want to merge all the tables in my environment starting with "m_".

This produces exactly what I want:

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(apropos("^m_")))
```

But it doesn't work when I attempt to transform this code into a user function:

```
    multi.merge <- function(...){
        x <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(apropos(...))
        return(x)
}

dt <- multi.merge("^m_")
```

Error: value for ‘m_table1’ not found

I have tried using different functions such as `get0` or `syms`, and different syntax just ends up with the same error. I suspect it's just something to do with a problem in the structure of the function that I don't understand.

**Is there any way to make this work?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `reduce` will `full_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
multi.merge <- function(pattern) {
        mget(ls(pattern = pattern, envir = .GlobalEnv), envir = .GlobalEnv)  %>%
              reduce(full_join)
  }

dt <- multi.merge("^m_")
```

#### data

```
m_table1 <- structure(list(col1 = 1:5), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

m_table2 <- structure(list(col1 = 2:7, value = c(0.620061606036922, -0.833792752750578, 
-0.939990781455841, 0.00275725433910228, 1.40140753383493, 0.708695548097395
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: This returns: **Error: `.x` is empty, and no `.init` supplied**

Could there be something wrong with my regular expression pattern? I have tables such as "m_table1", "m_table2" that I am trying to match. This should be correct? @akrun

Comment: Can you try `multi.merge("^m_table\\d+$")`

Answer (score 2):

Try sending a fixed argument in the function.

```
multi.merge <- function(pattern){
   Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(ls(pattern = pattern))
   #Or
   #Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(apropos(pattern))
}


dt <- multi.merge("^m_")
```