# Merge a list of dataframes that match a regex pattern - pandas

Tags: python, r, regex, pandas, merge

I wish to merge many different data frames with names that match a regular expression pattern. ***(NOT the column names, I mean the name of the dataframe itself).***

With credit to the accepted response on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38089010/merge-a-list-of-pandas-dataframes), I am able to get my desired output with:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'variable'), [df1, df2, df3])
```

But typing them all out is quite tedious. My desired data frames are all labelled with a prefix of "m_", so I was hoping there would be a **simple way of using regex to match all my data frames using "^m_"**.

In hopes of providing more context, [I have already made a post regarding this issue in RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59979831/r-get-a-list-of-tables-matching-regex-pattern-in-a-user-function). In fact, I already knew how to do this in R, but that question was regarding how to shove all the code into my own function (which I would also love to know how to do in this situation). So if it helps by any means, this is the **exact R equivalent of what I'm trying to do:**

```
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(apropos("^m_")))
```

And if possible, make my own function out of it like this (but still doing this with python instead):

```
multi.merge <- function(pattern){
    Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), mget(apropos(pattern), envir=.GlobalEnv))
}
output <- multi.merge("^m_")
```

But if you don't know what any of that means in R, hopefully my desired output is still clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
def global_pd_dfs(pattern=None, return_values=False):
    dct = globals()
    if pattern is None:
        return [dct[x] if return_values else x for x in dct.keys() if type(dct[x]) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame]
    else:
        pattern = re.compile(pattern)
        return [dct[x] if return_values else x for x in dct.keys() if type(dct[x]) == pd.core.frame.DataFrame and pattern.match(x)]

def multi_merge(pattern=None):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: pd.merge(x, y, on = 'variable'), global_pd_dfs(pattern=pattern, return_values = True))
```

If no pattern given, `global_pd_dfs()` lists all pandas dfs in global environment. And `multi_merge()` will try to merge all pandas dfs in global environment.

R's `ls()` can be mimicked by Pythons `globals()`, however, the last one is a dictionary.